# Invariance of Lagrangian under active coordinate transformation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, coordinate-systems

This question is related to symmetry properties of the Lagrangian and conservation laws. Let us consider a one-dimensional case of a particle of mass $m$ moving along the $x$ axis such that the Lagrangian is given by $L = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{x}^2 $. Now, if there is an active coordinate transformation such that the physical location of the point mass changes from $x$ to $x + \delta x$, then this must happen in some interval of time ($t,t+\delta t$). The particle was at location $x$ at time instant $t$ and is at location $x +\delta x$ at time $t + \delta t$. Since $\dot{x}$ is in general a function of time, the Lagrangian has an implicit time dependence. Then how are we sure that the Lagrangian does not change under an active coordinate transformation?

Comment: 'Active coordinate transformation' is a bit of a strange expression. My impression is that "passive transformations" are the same as "coordinate transformations."  "Active transformations" have no bearing on the coordinates: they signify change in location within a fixed coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

(Caveat: I'm new to this framework, and I do not pretend to be an expert.)

I think there is some confusion here about the nature of the transformation.  When you check to see if a spatial transformation leaves the Lagrangian invariant, you aren't applying the transformation over time, it gets applied instantaneously.

What you're describing (carrying out a translation over a short interval of time) sounds more like a [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)).

Now, it's perfectly fine to define a flow that's carrying point $A$ to point $B$ via translation over a certain amount of time. But you would not be checking for invariance with respect to the flow, you'd be checking with respect to the tangent lift of the transformation at a fixed time $t$.  These are all spatial changes that happen instantaneously: they are time independent. You're checking for invariance at each particular time-slice $t$, but it does not play into the transformation itself.  In the case of a constant speed translation, the transformation will be identical at every time $t$ anyhow.

So to recapitulate, you can evaluate whether or not a Lagrangian is invariant

1. With respect to a function $TM\to TM$; or
2. you can also evaluate whether or not the Lagrangian is invariant with respect to (all time-$t$ maps in) a flow.

The case of a translation carried out over time should be interpreted as the second one.  Each transformation that you are checking for invariance is independent of $t$, but the family of transformations involved in the flow could be considered as indexed by time.

> The matter could be kept a purely mathematical one: does the Lagrangian have any spatial dependence?

Surely, if I'm understanding you correctly. Consider the Lagrangian for gravitation of a small object with zero initial kinetic energy towards a massive object.  The only contribution to the Lagrangian then is the gravitational potential, which is weaker further out, and will yield a different value.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinate transformations have nothing to do with physically moving the particles from one location to another. Coordinate transformations, as is evident from it's name, are transformations applied to *our* chosen coordinates. This has **no effect on the physical reality**, thus the *"real"* positions and the momenta of the particles remains **unchanged**. And, if the Lagrangian stays invariant under any such coordinate transformation, we can then exploit that symmetry to find a conserved quantity of the morion, using [Noether's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem).

In the case of **active transformations**, they are characterised by [**virtual displacements**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_displacement). As the wiki states, in virtual displacements, time dependence is *not* considered. In other words, $\delta t=0$ when talking about virtual displacements. Thus, there is *no physical time elapse* occuring when you perform an active transformation.

Comment: I think the user is explicitly asking about the *other* type of transformation ("active transformation" that changes location but not the coordinate system.)

Comment: @rschwieb My bad. I edited the answer to include active transformations as wel. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks for answering @rschwieb and FakeMod. The matter could be kept a purely mathematical one: does the Lagrangian have any spatial dependence ? Attaching physical intuition to this i.e. Lagrangian is invariant under an active coordinate transformation, made things confusing. Anyway, my doubt is resolved.

Comment: @Tirthankar I appended a line to my post about your last query here.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks for providing an example of a spatially dependent Lagrangian.